# How to Select Specific Piece of HTML using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my goal for this code is to make it so when one of the tree branches is clicked, it changes the clicked `^` from a `^` to a `O` using JQuery and Javascript (this is for a school assignment). For example, if I clicked the very top `^` it would replace the `^` with an `O`, or if I clicked the very left `^` in the second row, it would change that `^` to a `O`, etc. I want to try and keep it rather simple and only add on to the existing code I already have rather than replacing all of it. I am a beginner when it comes to coding in Javascript and JQuery, so please avoid super-advanced tactics. Thank you very much.

Current Code:

````html
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Welcome to the Holiday Tree Simulator</h1>
  <ul>
   <li> Click a green branch (<font color=green>^</font>) to change it into a red ornament
   <li> Click a red ornament (<font color=red>O</font>) to turn it into an unlit light (only when power is off)
   <li> Click an unlit light (<font color=gray>*</font>) to turn it into a green branch (only when power is off)
  </ul>
<hr>
 <div id=treeArea align=center style="font-family: Courier">
  <font id=treeBranches style="font-family: Courier" color="green"></font>
  <font id=treeTrunk style="font-family: Courier" color="brown"></font>
 </div>
</div>
<hr>
Tree Size:<input type=text id=treeSize></input>
Trunk Size:<input type=text id=trunkSize></input>
<button id=new>New Tree</button><br>
Power: <span id=powerVal>OFF</span>
<button id=power>Toggle Power</button>
   </body>
   <script src=http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js type=text/javascript></script>
   <script type=text/javascript>
var treeSize = 8;
var trunkSize = 3;
for (var row=1 ; row<=treeSize ; row++){
 for (var col=1 ; col<=row ; col++)
  $("#treeBranches").append("^");
 $("#treeBranches").append("<br>");
}
for (var trunkrow=1 ; trunkrow<=trunkSize ; trunkrow++){
 for (var trunkcol=1 ; trunkcol<=2 ; trunkcol++)
  $("#treeTrunk").append("|");
 $("#treeTrunk").append("<br>");
}
//////////new tree//////////
$("#new").click(function newTree(){
 $("#treeBranches").html("")
 $("#treeTrunk").html("")
 treeSize = document.getElementById("treeSize").value;
 trunkSize = document.getElementById("trunkSize").value;
 for (var row=1 ; row<=treeSize ; row++){
  for (var col=1 ; col<=row ; col++)
   $("#treeBranches").append("^");
  $("#treeBranches").append("<br>");
 }
 for (var trunkrow=1 ; trunkrow<=trunkSize ; trunkrow++){
  for (var trunkcol=1 ; trunkcol<=2 ; trunkcol++)
   $("#treeTrunk").append("|");
  $("#treeTrunk").append("<br>");
 }
})
///////////change ornament/////////////
$("#treeBranches").click(function changeOrnament(){
 
})
///////////run newTree command////////////////
///////////run newTree command////////////////
</script>
</html>
```
````

Update: Here is the finished code to my project, thank you for your advice, I know this was a school project, but I didn't need the work done for me, I just needed to be pushed in the right direction, and you guys did that, so thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to the Holiday Tree Simulator</h1>
<ul>
  <li> Click a green branch (<font color=green>^</font>) to change it into a red ornament
  <li> Click a red ornament (<font color=red>O</font>) to turn it into an unlit light (only when power is off)
  <li> Click an unlit light (<font color=gray>*</font>) to turn it into a green branch (only when power is off)
</ul>

<hr>

<div id=treeArea align=center style="font-family: Courier">
<font id=treeBranches style="font-family: Courier" color="green"></font>
<font id=treeTrunk style="font-family: Courier" color="brown"></font>
</div>

<hr>

Tree Size:<input type=text id=treeSize></input>
Trunk Size:<input type=text id=trunkSize></input>
<button id=new>New Tree</button><br>
Power: <span id=powerVal>OFF</span>
<button id=power>Toggle Power</button>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" type=text/javascript></script>

<script type=text/javascript>
var treeSize = 8;
var trunkSize = 3;
for (var row=1 ; row<=treeSize ; row++)
{
 for (var col=1 ; col<=row ; col++)
  {
  $("#treeBranches").append("<font class='branches'>^</font>");
  }
 $("#treeBranches").append("<br>");
}
for (var trunkrow=1 ; trunkrow<=trunkSize ; trunkrow++)
{
 for (var trunkcol=1 ; trunkcol<=2 ; trunkcol++)
  $("#treeTrunk").append("|");
 $("#treeTrunk").append("<br>");
}
///////////change ornament/////////////
$(".branches").click(changeOrnament);
function changeOrnament()
{
 if ($(this).html()=="^")
  {
  $(this).attr("color","red");
  $(this).html("O");
  $(this).attr("class","not_ast")
  }
 else if ($(this).html()=="O" && power==0)
  {
  $(this).attr("color","gray");
  $(this).html("*");
  $(this).attr("class","ast")
  }
 else if ($(this).html()=="*" && power==0)
  {
  $(this).attr("color","green");
  $(this).html("^");
  $(this).attr("class","not_ast");
  }
}
//////////new tree//////////
$("#new").click(newTree);
function newTree()
{
 $("#treeBranches").html("")
 $("#treeTrunk").html("")
 treeSize = document.getElementById("treeSize").value;
 trunkSize = document.getElementById("trunkSize").value;
 for (var row=1 ; row<=treeSize ; row++)
 {
  for (var col=1 ; col<=row ; col++)
   {
   $("#treeBranches").append("<font class='new_branches'>^</font>");
   }
  $("#treeBranches").append("<br>");
 }
 for (var trunkrow=1 ; trunkrow<=trunkSize ; trunkrow++)
 {
  for (var trunkcol=1 ; trunkcol<=2 ; trunkcol++)
   $("#treeTrunk").append("|");
  $("#treeTrunk").append("<br>");
 }
 $(".new_branches").click(changeOrnament);
}
var power=0;
$("#power").click(powerToggle);
function powerToggle()
{
 if (power==0)
  {
  $("#powerVal").html("ON");
  power=1;
  $(".ast").attr("color","yellow");
  } 
 else
  {
  $("#powerVal").html("OFF");
  power=0;
  $(".ast").attr("color","gray");
  }
  
}
///////////run newTree command////////////////
///////////run newTree command////////////////


</script>



</html>
```

Comment: wrap each of the `^` in a span, then `$("#treeBranches span").click(..` the `$(this)` inside that event will refer to the single `^`, which you can apply your colour to

Comment: I'll upvote it since even though this is a school assignment, the fact that you've tried something on your own before coming here and asking for code is commendable.

Answer (score 4):

in generating tree loop, you need to replace following code

```
    $("#treeBranches").append("^");
```

with

```
    $("#treeBranches").append('<span class="leaf">^</span>');
```

it'll create every leaf as an accessible component

then following code will work to change particular leaf to ornament

```
    ///////////change ornament/////////////
    $(document).on('click','.leaf', function() {
        $(this).html('O');  
    })
    ///////////run newTree command////////////////
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is your solved homework. Also if this is not from the 1990s, don't use `<font>` tags.

```js
var treeSize = 8;
var trunkSize = 3;
for (var row=1 ; row<=treeSize ; row++)
{
 for (var col=1 ; col<=row ; col++)
  $("#treeBranches").append("<span class='leaf'>^</span>");
 $("#treeBranches").append("<br>");
}
for (var trunkrow=1 ; trunkrow<=trunkSize ; trunkrow++)
{
 for (var trunkcol=1 ; trunkcol<=2 ; trunkcol++)
  $("#treeTrunk").append("|");
 $("#treeTrunk").append("<br>");
}
//////////new tree//////////
$("#new").click(function newTree()
{
 $("#treeBranches").html("")
 $("#treeTrunk").html("")
 treeSize = document.getElementById("treeSize").value;
 trunkSize = document.getElementById("trunkSize").value;
 for (var row=1 ; row<=treeSize ; row++)
 {
  for (var col=1 ; col<=row ; col++)
   $("#treeBranches").append("^");
  $("#treeBranches").append("<br>");
 }
 for (var trunkrow=1 ; trunkrow<=trunkSize ; trunkrow++)
 {
  for (var trunkcol=1 ; trunkcol<=2 ; trunkcol++)
   $("#treeTrunk").append("|");
  $("#treeTrunk").append("<br>");
 }
})
///////////change ornament/////////////
$(document).on('click','.leaf', function() {
        $(this).html('O');  
    });
```

```css
.green {
 color: green;
 }
 
 .red {
 color: red;
 }
 
 .brown {
 color: brown;
 }
 
 .gray {
 color: grey;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Welcome to the Holiday Tree Simulator</h1>
<ul>
  <li> Click a green branch (<span class=green>^</span>) to change it into a red ornament
  <li> Click a red ornament (<span class=red>O</span>) to turn it into an unlit light (only when power is off)
  <li> Click an unlit light (<span class=gray>*</span>) to turn it into a green branch (only when power is off)
</ul>

<hr>

<div id="treeArea">
<font id="treeBranches" style="font-family: Courier" style="green"></font>
<font id="treeTrunk" style="font-family: Courier" style="brown"></font>
</div>


<hr>

<label>Tree Size:<input type=text id=treeSize></label>
<label>Trunk Size:<input type=text id=trunkSize></label>
<button id=new>New Tree</button><br>
<label>Power: <span id=powerVal>OFF</span></label>
<button id=power>Toggle Power</button>
```

Comment: He's just a beginner, we shouldn't give complete code. am i right?